# How can i embed NULL character inside string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, null

Can i use string in C++ which support embedded NULL character?

My issue is: 
Constructing string with embedded NULL and hence sent it to C++ DLL as an array of bytes.

```
    string inputStr("he\0llo", 6);
    int byteLength = 6;
    BYTE *inputByte = (BYTE*)(char*)inputStr.c_str();
    ApplyArabicMapping(inputByte , byteLength);
```

Comment: You'll have to be more clear than that...

Comment: why do you need that? the string class doesn't need the `'\0'` character to know that it ends.
furthermore, if you use the string.c_str() method, you get an array of characters **with** the `'\0'` character at the end.

Comment: @alegen none of that changes anything.

Comment: Usually \0 indicates the end of a string. So if you pass c_str() with nulls in the middle to a function expecting a null terminated string it won't use the full string, just up to the first null. Maybe you need `vector<char>` instead. Why do you need this?

Comment: Why not use an `std::vector<char>`? This makes clear it's not a regular string.

Comment: Downvoted: (It does not make that much of a difference to reputation) The answer is clearly incomplete, as the issue you are having is not with embedding a NUL character in a `string` (which in C++ would be `std::string` unless otherwise said), but rather in the use of a different interface. That is, the question lacks the most important bits of information, that are only sprinkled in comments.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `std::string` supports storing `NULL` characters because it is not `NULL`-terminated. You can create one in many ways:

```
string str("he\0llo", 6);
str.append(1, '\0');
str.push_back('\0');
const char[] cstr = "hell\0o";
string str2(cstr, cstr + sizeof(cstr) - 1); // - 1 for the NULL
```

Comment: Eventhough this is correct, i'd like to point out that `std::vector<char>` is functionally almost the same and has the advantage of making clear that you might find chars you don't expect in the container.

Comment: @RedX: I don't know, if it's still some kind of text string I'd still use `std::string`, while using `std::vector<unsigned char>` for binary data.

Comment: @RedX: *you might find chars you don't expect in the container* The problem with that statement is that it assumes that you should not expect a NUL in a `std::string`. I believe it is better to learn not to assume that and get over with. The difference between `std::string` and `std::vector<char>` is that the former indicates that you are storing *text* not just small numbers, and that it offers a much richer (too rich in places) for processing.

Comment: @AhmedMostafa: The problem is that you are trying to use a C string in the interface, and C strings don't allow for internal NUL characters (that and the casts have a funny smell, rethink them!). Because you cannot use NUL to determine the end of the string you will have to pass both the pointer to the first character and the length of the complete string (you seem to be doing that) **and** using the length inside the library ignoring the C string terminator. BTW, are you sure that your issue is not somewhere else? like the casts? (or in particular `(BYTE)`, could that be `BYTE*`?)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas One could argue that using `std::vector<char>` also says you're storing characters; I (and many others) would use `std::vector<signed char>` for small integers.  Still, `std::string` does seem to suggest some sort of actual text, whereas `std::vector<char>` suggests just a lot of characters.  I'd use `std::string` for text unless there were particular reasons not to, even though in practice, I never use anything that wouldn't work just as well with `std::vector<char>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *counted strings*, where the character buffer is stored alongside with its "content length"; this allows you to embed any character. `std::string`, for example, is a kind of counted string.

Obviously, you cannot pass such a string to a function that expects a classic C-string, because it will see the first null it encounters as the string terminator.

Comment: @AhmedMostafa maybe you should update the original question with your issue, as I (and possibly others) don't understand what you mean in the comment.