# C++ std::istringstream how to not terminate at '\0'

Tags: c++, stream, stringstream, istringstream, null-terminated

There is a function `Foo` that takes in an input stream of `char`. I want to call `Foo` from my function `Bar`, which takes in a C-style array with size. `char` is used to represent a byte (not using `std::byte` because it's difficult to get it working with streams).

```cpp
void Foo(std::basic_istream<char>& stream) { /* ... */ }

// absl::Span<const char> in my code, using char pointer
// and size here for simplicity.
void Bar(const char * const arr, const size_t size) {
  std::basic_istream<char> stream = ArrToStream(arr, size);
  foo(stream);
}
```

I'm struggling to implement `ArrToStream`.

If I pass an instance of `std::ifstream` to `Foo`, everything works as expected. When it comes to `ArrToStream`, seems like the most recommended approach is just to use `std::istringstream` like the following:

```cpp
std::basic_istream<char> ArrToStream(
  const char * const arr,
  const size_t size
) {
  return std::istringstream(arr, size);
}
```

However, this only works if there is no `'\0'` character in the array. There are many 0 bytes in my data, so the input string stream treats them as null terminators and stops reading the stream. I tried calling `stream.clear()` and `stream.seekg(...)` but no luck so far, the string stream simply refuse to read past 0's.

Is there a way to read or ignore `'\0'`? If not, what's the best way to represent byte streams in C++20?

Comment: *"the most recommended approach"* -- Where did you see this approach recommended? It does not appear to fit any of the [constructors of `istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream).

Comment: See [How can i embed NULL character inside string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10009917), with the caveat that as of C++17, `std::string_view` can be used instead of `std::string` (and would not involve copying the data).

Comment: The only public constructor of `std::basic_istream` is one taking a `streambuf*`; so for this code to compile, that's what `ArrToStream` would need to return. You seem to be trying to use the move constructor, but the move constructor is protected.

Comment: "Where did you see this approach recommended?"

I was referring to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43738691/2177724

"`std::string_view` can be used instead of `std::string`"

In my code I was constructing an `absl::Span<const char>` from `std::string_view`, and that seem to be the problem actually.

"You seem to be trying to use the move constructor"

I don't think that's related, both arguments are value type, so they are copied. You're right the way I constructed `std::istringstream` is the reason for bug though.

Comment: @Shuyang *"I was referring to this answer: stackoverflow.com/a/43738691/2177724"* -- Is that the right link? I see no mention there of `istringstream` nor of stream construction (the question and answers are about reading and writing streams, not constructing them).

Comment: I didn’t suspect how I called the constructor was the culprit, so I was referring to the use of char instead of std::byte. I read the way I used this constructor from another post, which I now know is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear (at least to me) what problem you're encountering. It's pretty easy to initialize a stringstream with a string that contains NUL characters:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    // a string of 100 NUL characters
    std::string data(100, '\0');

    // initialize the stream from that string
    std::istringstream input (data);

    // initialize a string with other characters:
    std::string data_read(20, '1');

    // read data from stream:
    if (input.read(data_read.data(), 20))
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
            // and assure that we read the NULs that we expected:
            assert(data_read[i] == '\0');
        }
    else
        std::cerr << "Read failed\n";
}
```

At least when I run this, it succeeds, indicating that the NULs were place in the stream, and that we successfully read them back out afterwards.

Comment: You're right, the problem is not `istringstream` terminating at 0, it's how I constructed it, it works fine in your example because you used `std::string`.

I read somewhere that one way to construct `istringstream` is to do what I did in my original code: `std::istringstream(arr, size);`, but I shouldn't have used it without checking the documentation. I'm actually calling `explicit istringstream (const string& str, ios_base::openmode which = ios_base::in);`, which implicitly created an `std::string` based on the C-style char array.